# NodeJs and systemd on raspbian error, MODULE_NOT_FOUND / Module._resolveFilename

Tags: systemd, raspbian

Hej!
I have a node script that I can run from anywhere on the system with

```
/usr/bin/node /home/admin/git-repos/MMMMobileAlerts/maserver/mobilealerts.js
```

Afer that I also added the x bit with

```
 sudo chmod +x /home/admin/git-repos/MMMMobileAlerts/maserver/mobilealerts.js
```

Now all I want is to run it as a service.
Therefore i created a `maserver.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system`

```
[Service]
ExecStart= /usr/bin/node /home/admin/git-repos/MMMMobileAlerts/maserver/mobilealerts.js
```

I also tried it with `#!`.

After i entered the command `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` I looked at
`sudo systemctl status maserver`

```
● maserver.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/maserver.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-08-21 10:00:16 CEST; 5h 9min ago
   Main PID: 2404124 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 234ms

Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi node[2404124]:     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi node[2404124]:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi node[2404124]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi node[2404124]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi node[2404124]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi node[2404124]:   requireStack: []
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi node[2404124]: }
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi node[2404124]: Node.js v18.17.1
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi systemd[1]: maserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 21 10:00:16 dockerpi systemd[1]: maserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I want to run an NodeJs scritpt as a service with systemd on raspbian.

Comment: does the command line version work as root? if not, that's perhaps the issue - also, by `!#` I assume you meant `#!` ... but exactly what did you do with the `#!`

Comment: As i have written, I can execute the script from anywhere on the system also with sudo.
Yes I tried the shebang, **sudo #!/usr/bin/node /home/admin/git-repos/MMMMobileAlerts/maserver/mobilealerts.js**

Comment: OK, you didn't mention sudo at all ... the shebang I used is `#!/usr/bin/env node` - but, I also make the systemd service files `WorkingDirectory` the same directory where the index.js file is - I know that shouldn't make a difference before you go off scraming again, just telling you what works for me - it's odd that the error message doesn't tell you WHICH module is not found

Comment: I have tried it many different ways...
Now I added the Working dir:
**[Service]
ExecStart=node git-repos/MMMMobileAlerts/maserver/mobilealers.js
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin/git-repos/MMMMobileAlerts/maserver**
But that wont work.

Comment: if `mobilealers.js` is `chmod a+x`, then change ExecStart `ExecStart=/home/admin/git-repos/MMMMobileAlerts/maserver/mobilealers.js` with the shebang I proposed

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue setting the User and Group directives of the service file as the ones set on the js called by Node:

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
```